# How to make something lwt supported?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen, ocaml-lwt

I am trying to understand the term `lwt supported`.

---

So assume I have a piece of code which connect a database and write some data: `Db.write conn data`. It has nothing to do with lwt yet and each write will cost `10 sec`.

Now, I would like to use lwt. Can I directly code like below?

```
let write_all data_list = Lwt_list.iter (Db.write conn) data_list
let _ = Lwt_main.run(write_all my_data_list)
```

Support there are `5` data items in `my_data_list`, **will all 5 data items be written into the database sequentially or in parallel?**

---

Also in Lwt manually or http://ocsigen.org/tutorial/application, they say

> Using Lwt is very easy and does not cause troubles, provided you never
>   use blocking functions (non cooperative functions). Blocking functions
>   can cause the entre server to hang!

**I quite don't understand how to *not* using blocking functions.** For every my own function, can I just use `Lwt.return` to make it `lwt support`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. The principle of `lwt supported` is that everything that can potentially take time in your code should return an Lwt value.

About Lwt_list.iter, you can choose whether you want the treatment to be parallel or sequential, by choosing between `iter_p` and `iter_s` :

> In iter_s f l, iter_s will call f on each elements
> of l, waiting for completion between each element. On the
> contrary, in iter_p f l, iter_p will call f on all
> elements of l, then wait for all the threads to terminate.

About the non-blocking functions, the principle of the Light Weight Threads is that they keep running until they reach a "cooperation point", i.e. a point where the thread can be safely interrupted or has nothing to do, like in a `sleep`.

But you have to declare you enter a "cooperation point" before actually doing the `sleep`. This is why the whole Unix library has been wrapped, so that when you want to do an operation that takes time (e.g. a `write`), a cooperation point is automatically reached.

For your own function, if you use IOs operations from Unix, you should instead use the Lwt version (`Lwt_unix.sleep` instead of `Unix.sleep`)

Comment: In your example `Lwt_unix.sleep` instead of `Unix.sleep`, should I do anything special for my `Db.write conn data`?

Comment: Making it return a lwt value should be enough in your case.